# Can a class in one WAR be referenced in web.xml of another WAR in the same EAR, in Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader, wildfly, ear

I have an ear with 2 .war files.

In war #1, under WEB-INF/classes/com/my there is a BatchTriggerBuildServlet.class

In war #2 i have the following in its web.xml (in its WEB-INF)
(a reference to a class in war #1):

```
<web-app id="WebApp">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BatchTriggerBuildServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>BatchTriggerBuildServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.my.BatchTriggerBuildServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BatchTriggerBuildServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/BatchTriggerBuildServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</web-app>
```

This is deployed in Wildfly 10.
I also have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the META-INF folder of the containing .ear containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
        <!-- Make sub deployments NOT isolated by default, so they can see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Is this legitimate? Because I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException for the above class when i try to deploy the ear, along with the message that it

```
"Failed to start service ... from [Module "<my ear name>.<my war #2 name>:main" from Service Module Loader]"
```

Is there a way to get this to work?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ear-subdeployments-isolated` does not apply to web modules, which are always isolated from each other. See [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly).

Try moving the classes and their dependencies into a jar in the EAR/lib directory.